# Websphere admin account locked

Tags: websphere

The administrator account to login to WAS admin console is locked out. Is there a way for the developer to unlock the account? I looked at this link:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v5r6m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/tsewc55securityguide32.htm
But I am not sure what they mean by WebSphere Commerce database name

Comment: what version of WebSphere do you use? Is it 5 or 6/7? To be able to login to console (and possibly change security settings), you can look for `security.xml` file in your profile (WAS 6, 7) and change `securityEnabled` attribute to `false`. Also - you haven't provided enough details - you can have your account disabled for example in LDAP directory if that's how you've configured WAS Security.

Comment: Thank you. Cannot find the attribute securityEnabled in security.xml. I think it must be set up in LDAP directory...I am not sure of the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kaushik,

As suggested by  Grzegorz Grzybek you should be able to turn the security to false by changing the security.xml

However it is preferred that you don't touch any of the configuration files by hand.

The preffered way to do this is to use wsadmin with a conntype NONE.

Refer to: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fusec_rgsp.html

If your server does not restart after you enable global security, you can disable security. Go to your $install_root/bin directory and run the wsadmin -conntype NONE command. At the wsadmin> prompt, enter securityoff and then type exit to return to a command prompt. Restart the server with security disabled to check any incorrect settings through the administrative console.

Also refer to: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173912

This is applicable to a number of WAS versions including the latest ones.

This is a back door for you to use in scenarios like this.

HTH

Manglu